# oracle apex 18.2 pl/sql function body returning sql query checking page item value

Tags: oracle-apex

I am Creating a interacitve repor `pl/sql function body returning sql query`
I have a page item `:P1_DIVISION_ID`  to pass as parameter as well as check item value is not null as show below

```
declare
lv_query varchar2(4000);
begin
IF :P1_DIVISION_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
select 'select DIVISION,
       CUSTOMER_ID,
       PARTY_NAME,
       ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
       ORG_ID,
       OU_NAME,
       AGING_1_30,
       AGING_31_60,
       AGING_61_90,
       ABOVE_90,
       CURRENT_BALANCE,
       PAST_DUE,
       WEBSITE_STATUS,
       BLOCK_DATE,
       BLOCK_REASON,
       TOTAL_NUM_LOGIN,
       CP_LAST_PAY_DT,
       CP_LAST_AMT,
       CP_LAST_PAY_MODE,
       CP_AGE,
       CP_STATUS,
       CP_DATE,
       CP_DEFF,
       CP_UNBILL,
       CP_PHONE,
       CP_EMAIL,
       CP_ACCT_MGR,
       FU_ASSIGN,
       CP_LTR_SENT_DATE,
       CP_LTR_TYPE,
       CP_COMMENTS,
       COMMENTS
  from XX_CUSTOMER_AGING_V WHERE DIVISION '||:P1_DIVISION_ID INTO lv_query
FROM DUAL;
END IF;


RETURN lv_query;


end;
```

BUT when i validate the query it show me the below errors

`ORA-20999: WWV_FLOW_EXEC.NULL_QUERY_RETURNED_BY_FUNCTION`

Suggestion required to handle the error

Answer (score 2):

1. What is the query like when `P1_DIVISION_ID`? This function is returning a null because you didn't specify one, and hence the error.
2. Don't do `select ... into lv_query from dual`. Just assign the string to the variable.
3. Your function isn't doing much so why are you even doing this? Why not just a SQL query for the source?

Comment: +1; there's nothing *dynamic* in that query, so - no point in a function that returns a query. A simple `SELECT  whatever FROM XX_CUSTOMER_AGING_V WHERE DIVISION = :P1_DIVISION_ID` would suffice.

Comment: I have 4 difference where clauses on the basis of 4 page items , i want to check if any of page item is not null the same query will be returned with some different where clause

Comment: We don't see that level of detail in your question, so you are the best judge on whether the query by function is appropriate. I have rarely used this as a source since most use cases are met with a carefully crafted WHERE clause. If this is necessary, just make sure that the function **always** returns a valid SQL query.

Comment: And build your bind variables into the query string - don't concanate them, which transforms them into literals.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a function with your code:

```
create or replace function get_my_query return VARCHAR2 
is
lv_query varchar2(4000);
begin
  IF v('P1_DIVISION_ID') IS NOT NULL THEN
    return q'!select DIVISION,
       CUSTOMER_ID,
       PARTY_NAME,
       ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
       ORG_ID,
       OU_NAME,
       AGING_1_30,
       AGING_31_60,
       AGING_61_90,
       ABOVE_90,
       CURRENT_BALANCE,
       PAST_DUE,
       WEBSITE_STATUS,
       BLOCK_DATE,
       BLOCK_REASON,
       TOTAL_NUM_LOGIN,
       CP_LAST_PAY_DT,
       CP_LAST_AMT,
       CP_LAST_PAY_MODE,
       CP_AGE,
       CP_STATUS,
       CP_DATE,
       CP_DEFF,
       CP_UNBILL,
       CP_PHONE,
       CP_EMAIL,
       CP_ACCT_MGR,
       FU_ASSIGN,
       CP_LTR_SENT_DATE,
       CP_LTR_TYPE,
       CP_COMMENTS,
       COMMENTS
    from XX_CUSTOMER_AGING_V WHERE DIVISION=:P1_DIVISION_ID!';
  END IF;
end;
```

and than, use this function in the `PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query`:

```
return get_my_query;
```

Comment: If he REALLY wants to create an IR of the type "pl/sql function body returning sql query", I agree that wrapping it in a function is the way to go.

But based on the conversation before, it doesn't seem to me that he **really** needs to do that at all. He would get faster results querying all 4 fields at once, handling null parameters values correctly.